# Is it possible to intercept events on Office.js?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, word-addins

I'm new to Office.js and I wanted to know if is possible to intercept when user saves the document, opens it, prints it, etc. And if it is, how do I do it?

Comment: You might start by working through the documentation. For example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events

Comment: OP and @CindyMeister Document Saving, opening, printing, etc events are not available in Office.js. The feature has been requested a lot on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/ however though.

Answer (score 1):

For open the add-in, you could use

```
Office.onReady();
{
  Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    // your code logic here
    console.log("Start");
    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

So far we dont have onSaved events, as we have autosave feature, the document will be autosaved. So we decide not to provide onSaved event.